# Unable to scroll when modal is opened.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When the user selects the link for the modal, the body overflow is hidden, but the scrolling for the modal is hidden as well even when I have the modal as being overflow: auto. I would like for the modal to be able to scroll without what is behind the overlay to scroll as well.

HTML

```
<a>View Proposal Details</a>
<div class='popup'>
<div class="popup-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.     Nulla lobortis quis mauris tristique rutrum. Suspendisse nisi turpis, pharetra porta porta eu, interdum ac eros. Praesent nisl nunc, laoreet ut consectetur sed, interdum ac ligula. Aliquam sit amet efficitur velit. Donec malesuada nec est ac feugiat. Nam gravida ornare volutpat. Vivamus ipsum mi, laoreet sed mattis id, rutrum sit amet massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Nullam congue auctor ligula at venenatis. Integer varius tortor quis lacus    luctus, vel dignissim leo tincidunt. Aliquam eleifend cursus vulputate. Sed vitae dolor at elit porta tristique. In quam arcu, posuere ac lorem nec, finibus imperdiet nibh. Etiam eu tincidunt metus, nec tristique eros. Nullam tempor lorem sed sapien scelerisque, nec rutrum risus tempor. Sed blandit ipsum accumsan ipsum porta consectetur. Curabitur imperdiet justo non purus euismod blandit. Ut cursus dolor mauris, vitae sagittis nisl sagittis at. Sed in feugiat nisi. Pellentesque egestas mi a mi dictum, vel posuere risus malesuada. Etiam tincidunt volutpat neque, vel lobortis orci tristique in. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam sed rutrum orci.

Proin pellentesque arcu ut justo ullamcorper dignissim. Sed eget enim sed nibh convallis maximus ac ac odio. In tortor risus, luctus sit amet enim non, luctus faucibus leo. Nulla nec mauris vitae mauris tincidunt mollis nec sit amet velit. Proin gravida neque eu eros blandit vulputate. Fusce tristique interdum scelerisque. 
            Donec vel laoreet nunc, in tristique risus. Phasellus ultrices orci mi, eget imperdiet libero ultrices quis. Phasellus iaculis, ante et dictum mollis, est ipsum feugiat turpis, condimentum sagittis ligula diam a erat. Donec porta, magna sit amet pellentesque pharetra, erat turpis semper lorem, ac varius metus arcu et felis. Vestibulum facilisis ac lorem ut blandit.


            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .popup { position:fixed;z-index:8;left:31%;width:625px;padding:0;top:70px;background:#fff;overflow:auto;display:none;box-shadow:5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25)}
```

JQuery

```
function opendialog(container) { 
$(container).fadeIn();  //open
if( $(container).height() < $(window).height() ) {  //centralize vertically
    $(container).css({
        'top':'50%',
        'margin-top':'-'+$(container).height()/2+'px'
    });
} else {
    $(container).css('position','absolute');
}
$('.overlay').fadeIn();
}

$('.cancel').click(function(){ //close clicking on overlay, close button and cancel button
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    closedialog();
})
$('a').click(function(){
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');    
  opendialog('.popup');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the body to scroll, just remove the line

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

If you want the modal itself to move down the screen, you'll want to add an outer div that takes up the entire page and apply `overflow: scroll` to that.

```
<div id="popup-outer">
    <div id="popup">[...]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this as an example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZBovY - I would like for the scroll action to be exactly like this. However mine is built entirely different and not just with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to do this is to set fixed values for top, bottom, left, and right, removing the value for width.  Then you can be assured your modal is always centered and optimally sized for the screen, and, of course, you won't shove your scrollbar off-screen right.

```
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 8;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
```

You can also keep the width fixed and set margin-left and margin-right to auto provided that all container elements have some sort of width set, so that that the browser can actually calculate the margins.

Simple fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jv6uzh3s/2/).